# Apple Mach-O Linker Errors after restarting mac

Tags: ios, xcode

I was prompted to restart the computer after a few updates were installed and since then my app keeps failing to build.  It was working fine prior to restarting the computer.  I don't believe xcode was one of the updates.  I am currently running Xcode Version 4.6.3 (4H1503).

```
Apple Mach-O Linker errors:

(null): "_main", referenced from:

(null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have tried removing all frameworks and adding them back.

Any idea what is causing the app to fail to build now?

Comment: Might be a silly questions, but did you try cleaning your project? CMD+SHIFT+K

Comment: Yes, I have tried to clean the project.  I finally figured out the problem and will be posting the solution in a second.  I don't know what happened but the project got messed up after the computer rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

After spending many hours trying to figure out what happened I finally discovered that somehow with the installation of the updates and restarting the computer many files were no longer listed in the Compile Sources section.

I have no idea why it happened.

To solve the issue I just had to add the files back.
[image: Compile Source]

If you're like me and have no clue what files actually are suppose to be there I just added all files available and then Xcode raised a warning stating which files it could not understand.  I just went and removed any file that xcode didn't like in the Compiled Sources section.

Yes I know this a very crude way of handling it, but my project is working again now and that makes me happy. :-)